# iOS: Change UINavigationBar color while the app is running

Tags: ios, swift

Basically I want to have a button that changes the navigation bar color globally (I have a horizontally paging scrollview with multiple navigation controllers). I can easily set the initial color in the `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` with `UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor`, but I can't seem to be able to change it later or while the app is running.

What I have tried:
Have `AppDelegate` conform to a `didSetColor` protocol, that is called whenever the button is pressed, and contains the same `UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor` stuff, which doesn't work. I've tried changing the color in each navigation controller but that doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `appearance` is only for new widgets. To change an existing widget you have to call `barTintColor` on the existing widget directly.

Comment: @rmaddy ohhh. well this is good to know. Thank you; worst case I can go through and set each to the right color. I guess there wouldn't be any easy way to do it globally through appdelegate then, if I need to reference each specifically. Thanks again!!

Comment: You have to reload your scrollview or any container view which contain all navigation controllers.